# Align images to right of the main image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-gallery

I just want the large image to display on the left hand side, and the smaller images (grid layout - repeat(2, 1fr) in this fraction) to align on the RIGHT.

But its showing like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S76jN.png

Totally there are seven small images and one big image. I am just trying to code an image gallery using HTML CSS JS.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.main-img img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
}

.images img {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}

.images {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="main-img">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/264109/pexels-photo-264109.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=baby-children-cute-264109.jpg&fm=jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/35537/child-children-girl-happy.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-beautiful-boy-35537.jpg&fm=jpg">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/708440/pexels-photo-708440.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beard-bonding-community-708440.jpg&fm=jpg">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/35188/child-childrens-baby-children-s.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=boy-brother-child-35188.jpg&fm=jpg">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/670720/pexels-photo-670720.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=alone-clouds-golden-hour-670720.jpg&fm=jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not setting width correctly. You should set width on the wrappers. Also don't forget to use `Float:left` in order to have images oneline. I have removed `float:right` and `display:inline-block` from img elements as these are not necessary, Consider the following example :

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.main-img{
width:70%;
float:left;
}
.main-img img{
width:100%
}

.images img {
    width: 100%;
}

.images {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="main-img">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/264109/pexels-photo-264109.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=baby-children-cute-264109.jpg&fm=jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/35537/child-children-girl-happy.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=adorable-beautiful-boy-35537.jpg&fm=jpg">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/708440/pexels-photo-708440.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beard-bonding-community-708440.jpg&fm=jpg">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/35188/child-childrens-baby-children-s.jpg?cs=srgb&dl=boy-brother-child-35188.jpg&fm=jpg">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/670720/pexels-photo-670720.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=alone-clouds-golden-hour-670720.jpg&fm=jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
```